# How to convert string date to numeric in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have read a csv file with the command :

```
df=df.read_csv("path",parse_dates=[['Local Date', 'Local Time']])
```

I have the following output :

```
             created_at     Close      Open    Volume     Day
0      01-Mar-2019 00:47  25916.00  25916.00    141383   STABLE
1      01-Mar-2019 00:21  25916.00  25916.00         1   STABLE
2      01-Mar-2019 00:20  25916.00  25916.00        74   STABLE
3      01-Mar-2019 00:19  25916.00  25916.00       222   STABLE
4      01-Mar-2019 00:18  25916.00  25916.00    108257   STABLE
...           ...           ...        ...         ...     ...
```

I would like to convert the column "created_at" in the following way :

```
           created_at     Close      Open    Volume     Day
0      01-03-2019 00:47  25916.00  25916.00    141383   STABLE
1      01-03-2019 00:21  25916.00  25916.00         1   STABLE
2      01-03-2019 00:20  25916.00  25916.00        74   STABLE
3      01-03-2019 00:19  25916.00  25916.00       222   STABLE
4      01-03-2019 00:18  25916.00  25916.00    108257   STABLE
...           ...           ...        ...         ...     ...
```

I would like to "convert" the month that is written in "letters" form into a "numerical" form.

[Csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrurU.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you get stuck?

Comment: I tried to use :
`df.created_at.str.replace("Mar",03)`

It works but I would say it is not really efficient if I want to do it for every month :/

Comment: So not working if `parse_dates=['created_at'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael I am not sure what do you mean by `parse_dates=['created_at'])`
The column created is already in parse_dates

Comment: @stefan - So what are original data, first 5 rows before `df=df.read_csv("path",parse_dates=[['Local Date', 'Local Time']])` ?

Comment: @jezrael - I just add a screenshoot of the csv file in the post

Comment: @stefan, try using `pd.to_datetime` that should work for you.

Comment: Check dupe, solution is `df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])`

Comment: That what i mentioned `df['created_at'] =`  Just suffix to add to make it effective to DF. However  the Question doesn't seems to be exact duplicate what you marked it for it should `possible duplicate`  ,read question again carefully and thoroughly!

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your answers, the solution works well with `df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])`

Comment: @stefan, thats should work as i mentioned in my answer, you just need assign the new value to the column  to see the change :-)

Comment: @stefan, can you check what the column datatypes are: print(df.dtypes)

Comment: @MEdwin It was written :
`created_at     object
Close         float64
Open           object
Volume         object
Day            object
dtype: object`

Comment: Perfect. Try this:  df['created_at_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') # Creates a new column with the format that you are after. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @MEdwin It works very well! Thank you

Comment: Super! I am glad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

df['dt2'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

First it will convert string to date then it  will convert it in the string with desired format.

Answer (score 1):

Just to test try converting your column `created_at` into `pd.to_datetime`

### DataFrame

```
>>> df
          created_at
0  01-Mar-2019 00:47
1  01-Mar-2019 00:21
2  01-Mar-2019 00:20
```

### Result:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
0   2019-03-01 00:47:00
1   2019-03-01 00:21:00
2   2019-03-01 00:20:00
Name: created_at, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Just for the curiosity sake, as mentioned in the comment this can be changed directly to dataframe as follows:

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately the code work but there is absolutely no changes

Comment: @stefan, if answers helped you mark this as accepted answer [help is here to get it :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)